# Encode a string as httpBody via URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a POST login API that accepts password parameter as a simple string in httpBody.
This is like swagger call appears:

[image]

Now, I'm using **Alamofire**, and I want to encode it in my `URLRequest` via `ParameterEncoder`. I'm trying to use `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` but with no success.

This my `Routable` protocol:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum EncodeMode {
    case encoding(parameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding, parameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: [HTTPHeader]? = nil)
    case encoder(parameterEncoder: ParameterEncoder, parameter: Encodable, urlParameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: [HTTPHeader]? = nil)
}

protocol Routeable: URLRequestConvertible {
    
    var baseURL: URL { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var encodeMode: EncodeMode { get }
}

extension Routeable {
    
    // MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        var urlRequest: URLRequest
        switch encodeMode {
        case .encoding(let parameterEncoding, let parameters, let headers):
            urlRequest = try parameterEncoding.encode(URLRequest(url: url), with: parameters)
            urlRequest.method = method
            headers?.forEach { urlRequest.headers.add($0) }
        case .encoder(let parameterEncoder, let parameter, let urlParameters, let headers):
            urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(URLRequest(url: url), with: urlParameters)
            urlRequest.method = method
            urlRequest = try parameterEncoder.encode(parameter, into: urlRequest)
            headers?.forEach { urlRequest.headers.add($0) }
        }
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

and this my `UserRouter`

```
enum UserRouter: Routeable2 {
    
    case login(email: String,
               password: String)
    
    var encodeMode: EncodeMode {
        switch self {
        case let .login(email, password):
            return .encoder(parameterEncoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default,
                            parameter: password,
                            urlParameters: ["email": email])
        }
    }

.....
    
}
```

and this the returned error

> **No request created yet.**

I tried to debug and I think the problem is in the `encode(_ value: Encodable)` func inside `URLEncodedFormEncoder` class, but I don't know if it's a bug in Alamofire or I'm not doing something right.

```
    public func encode(_ value: Encodable) throws -> String {
        let component: URLEncodedFormComponent = try encode(value)

        guard case let .object(object) = component else {
            throw Error.invalidRootObject("\(component)") // <-- throw this error
        }

        let serializer = URLEncodedFormSerializer(alphabetizeKeyValuePairs: alphabetizeKeyValuePairs,
                                                  arrayEncoding: arrayEncoding,
                                                  keyEncoding: keyEncoding,
                                                  keyPathEncoding: keyPathEncoding,
                                                  spaceEncoding: spaceEncoding,
                                                  allowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)
        let query = serializer.serialize(object)

        return query
    }
```

Comment: You can't use `AF.request(...)` that will do it for your? Why do you need to do it yourself?

Comment: But urlEncoded usually use key/value, so it wouldn't surprises me it expects `["password": password"]` to work. Just write the value into the body, no?

Comment: `Cause I'm using a Router. I try to edit my question.

Comment: I realised, I do the same too. The issue is that you can't use `URLEncoded` with a "String", you need a Dictionary at least. So just do `urlRequest.httpBody = Data(password.utf8)`, when there are strange "encoding", do it manually.

Comment: Thank you @Larme. I'll use your suggestion but I'm still interested to know if this is some sort of problem with `Alamofire` or what.

Comment: @Larme In `URLEncodedFormComponent` enum I see a `string` case. So I tend to think that `Alamofire` should handle my use case

Comment: @Giorgio A single string is not a valid form encoding. Fundamentally form encoding is a key / value encoding, so simple strings won't work. And in any cast, if you already have the body value you don't need to use an encoding at all, just compose your `URLRequest` and pass that to Alamofire.

Comment: I tested, and it throws because is a String. It allows only `case let .object(object) = component`, is a Dictionary I guess...

Comment: Also, "No request created yet." isn't an error, it's just the `description` while the request is being created asynchronously. Errors will be provided in the completion handler or the result of the await.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larme and @Jon Shier suggestions I ended up to update my `Routable` protocol in this way:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum EncodeMode {
    case encoding(parameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding, parameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: [HTTPHeader]? = nil)
    case encoder(parameterEncoder: ParameterEncoder, parameter: Encodable, urlParameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: [HTTPHeader]? = nil)
    case string(parameter: String, urlParameters: Parameters? = nil, headers: [HTTPHeader]? = nil)
}

protocol Routable: URLRequestConvertible {
    
    var baseURL: URL { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var encodeMode: EncodeMode { get }
}

extension Routable {
    
    // MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        var urlRequest: URLRequest
        switch encodeMode {
        case .encoding(let parameterEncoding, let parameters, let headers):
            urlRequest = try parameterEncoding.encode(URLRequest(url: url), with: parameters)
            urlRequest.method = method
            headers?.forEach { urlRequest.headers.add($0) }
        case .encoder(let parameterEncoder, let parameter, let urlParameters, let headers):
            urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(URLRequest(url: url), with: urlParameters)
            urlRequest.method = method
            urlRequest = try parameterEncoder.encode(parameter, into: urlRequest)
            headers?.forEach { urlRequest.headers.add($0) }
        case .string(let parameter, let urlParameters, let headers):
            urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(URLRequest(url: url), with: urlParameters)
            urlRequest.method = method
            urlRequest.httpBody = parameter.data(using: .utf8)
            headers?.forEach { urlRequest.headers.add($0) }
        }
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

Basically, I added a `.string` case to handle my login API use case.

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to do here, but a JSON content type for form encoded data is wrong. Nor should you need to pass it through `URLEncoding` in the first place if all you're doing is putting the string the body.

Comment: @JonShier I have two parameters: email/username has to be passed as url encoded parameter and then I have to pass password as an httpBody string. So my `string` case takes `parameter` and `urlParameters` parameters (excuse the pun). I have to add the JSON content type because without it API responds 404 (I don't know why).

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. Yeah, Alamofire doesn't have a good abstraction for parameters that go in multiple places at the same time.

Comment: @JonShier do you think can make sense add something like `Routable`protocol inside the `Alamofire` framework?

Comment: Not really, given the sheer variety of ways you can compose routes and requests. To cover every bit of functionality people would need it would have to be huge.